# Netty Bootstrap options documentation

Tags: java, netty

In [Netty](http://netty.io/) there is a class called Bootstrap that can has a method `public <T> B option(ChannelOption<T> option, T value)`. Bootstrap class is used to configure channels options with provided parameters. The problem is that I am unable to find any documentation of what these parameters are and how do they affect communications between channels.

Answer (score 3):

The channel options are a super-set of the [standard Java socket options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/socketOpt.html) and some Netty specific ones.

[Full list of valid options documented here](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOption.html).